# Multiple objects containing SerialPort with same SerialDataReceivedEventHandler

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port

I have two objects (of the same class) which each contain a `SerialPort` object. The class has a method which handles the `SerialPort.DataReceived` event and is used by both `SerialPort` objects.

When I instantiate each object in a separate application, each port handles its `DataReceived` event individually as expected.

When I instantiate two instances of the `COM_Front_End` class in the same application and send data from one serial port to the other, both port's `DataReceived` event handlers fire. For short, I'll call this "cross-talk".

My class structure looks something like this:

```
public class COM_Front_End
{
    private SerialPort_custom port;
    private LockObject;

    public COM_Front_End(string PortName, string BaudRate)
    {
        // Other code

        port = new SerialPort_custom(PortName, BaudRate, new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialDataReceived));

        port.Open();
    }

    private void SerialDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //lock (LockObject)  // A lock is not needed here. Only one SerialDataReceived event can fire at a time
        //{
            SerialPort port;

            try
            {
                port = sender as SerialPort;

                if (port != null)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
                    int bytesRead = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    foreach (byte inByte in buffer)
                    {
                        // Byte processing code
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception handling code
            }
        //}
    }
}
```

The class containing the actual `SerialPort` class looks like:

```
public class SerialPort_custom : SerialPort
{
    public SerialPort_custom(string PortName, int BaudRate, SerialDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceivedHandler)
    {
        this.PortName = PortName;
        this.BaudRate = BaudRate;
        this.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        this.DataBits = 8;
        this.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
        this.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
        this.RtsEnable = true;
        this.DtrEnable = true;
        this.DiscardNull = false;
        this.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

        this.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

I have two instances of the `COM_Front_End` class in the same application. Whenever one instance receives data, both objects' `SerialDataReceived` methods fire.

Why does the `DataReceived` event handler fire for both serial ports when they are instantiated in the same application? Furthermore, how can I ensure that multiple instantiation of this class does not cause "cross-talk"?

Comment: Moderators: I could not think of a better title for my question. Any adjustments to the title to make it more concise are very welcome.

Comment: In the first part of the question you say that you are sending data from one port to the other - so have connected both together. Have you checked what happens if you send serial data from a separate source (another PC) to a single port on your application - do both event handlers still fire? Also have you checked with a different application if sending data between the two ports causes data to arrive at both (back in the days I worked a lot with serial ports then I used HyperTerminal and other applications like PCAnywhere - not sure what is available these days).

Comment: I connected one of the serial port to an external serial source and did not find that both serial ports had data receive events.

Comment: Glad you found the problem.  One question, why are you locking in the handler?  A serial port can only have one of its events being processed at a time.

Comment: @dbasnett : It shouldn't really be there. It was a last-ditch effort to troubleshoot the aforementioned issue I was having. I've edited the problem statement to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the root cause of my problem:

The project in which the `COM_Front_End` resides has two static classes. One of these classes is the Receive Buffer and the other the Transmit Buffer. Changing these classes so that they are not static solved my problem. Within each `COM_Front_End` object is a task which polls the Receive Buffer. Since they both use the same static class, they both were pulling from this buffer which explains why

A. The `SerialDataReceived` for both objects fired.

B. The data received for each was mangled/partial.

TL;DR: Non-static objects containing static objects will yield shared resources whether it is intended or not.

Please correct me wherever my explanation is faulty or incomplete.